# aws AmazonDynamoDBSessionManagerForTomcat ClassNotFound issue

Tags: amazon-web-services

I have created a simple aws web project using the Eclipse sdk.
I checked on Session Management using dynamo db so that my sessions are not sticky and they can persist if the load balancer adds or removes instances.

This project has a simple Object

```
package com.ns.ts.dto;
```

import java.io.Serializable;

public class User implements Serializable{

```
 /**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = -7038692393544658830L;
private String user;
    private String name;

    public String getUser() {
        return user;
    }

    public void setUser(String user) {
        this.user = user;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
```

}

And there are two servlets, setUser (which takes some parameters and sets user in the session with some values)
and getUser (which displays the user values from the session)

I deploy the project and all seems fine. A table gets created in DynamoDB.

Now I call setUser. This sets the object User in the session with some values.

Next, I call getUser and this displays the values of the User object from the session.
(Seems that the session is still in the EC2 instance)

I wait for some time and again call setUser with a different set of parameters.
I am watching the table in DynamoDB to make sure that the session object is in the table (I confirm this by last updated time for the row)

I wait for some time and again call getUser.

This throws an error:

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:com.ns.ts.dto.User

The error is generated at

com.amazonaws.tomcatsessionmanager.amazonaws.services.dynamodb.sessionmanager.DynamoDBSessionStore.load

I think this error is generates when the jar tries to deserilize the session object from dynampDB and it cant find the classpath for my custom object in the shared lib of Tomcat.

Is there anybody who has faced this before ?
Is there a work around / solution for using custom objects in a session and store them the dynamoDB ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an update and this problem seems to be have resolved.

https://github.com/aws/aws-dynamodb-session-tomcat/issues/3

Answer (score 1):

If the jar containing your User class is located under the `WEB-INF/lib` directory of your webapp, try moving it under Tomcat's `lib` directory. It probably needs to be alongside the Amazon jar for the class loading to work correctly.

Comment: The user Class is compiled as a class file under web-inf/classes. I also tried to place that in a jar file as a library. Placed the library in WEB-INF/lib and also moved it to Tomcat's lib. In this case it gave me an ClassCastException: Cannot cast com.com.ns.ts.dto.User to com.com.ns.ts.dto.User !!!

Comment: I am assuming that its pretty basic to store custom objects in session ? How is this managed otherwise, in a clustered environment where tomcat deserializes the session which has custom objects

Comment: I think you are on the right path by putting this jar under Tomcat's lib dir. Now make sure that the User class is no longer present under `webapp/WEB-INF`, otherwise it may be loaded by two different classloaders and could be the cause of the ClassCastException.

Comment: In that case how do I build the application. I tried adding the .ebextensions to the build path, so I do not get a compile error.

Comment: Add the jar containing User to your classpath when you compile.

Comment: This has solved the issue.....but then each time I modify my bean, I will have to create a jar file of the same...just wondering if there is a cleaner solution ?